# Current playlist with Spotipy

Tags: python-3.x, spotify, spotipy

I'm trying to loop over the tracks in the current playlist using Spotipy.

However, I've got two stumbling blocks:

1, Being about to work out the format of information from Spotipy `sp.current_user_playing_track()` - I tried a JSON pretty print which didn't work as it was "invalid"

2, Accessing the current playlist from the current track

This is what I have so far:

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
import spotipy.util as util

MY_ID   = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
SECRET = "000000000000000000000000000000000"

# Authorise
spoti = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=MY_ID,
                                                           client_secret=SECRET))
spoti.trace = False

username = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
scope    = "user-read-currently-playing"
redirect_uri = "my_callback"
token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope, client_id=MY_ID, client_secret=SECRET, redirect_uri=redirect_uri)

# sp as spotify - makes it easier
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)

current_track = sp.current_user_playing_track()
song_artist = current_track["item"]["artists"][0]["name"]
print(song_artist)

## trying to get current playlist
# current_playlist = current_track["item"]["playlist"] # wrong, but I know that now
# current_playlist = current_track["item"]["playlist"][0] # wrong, but I know that now
# current_playlist = current_track["context"]["playlist"] # keyError: "playlist"
# current_playlist = current_track["context"] # no print
# current_playlist = current_track["external_urls"] # keyError: "external_urls"
```

Comment: You are mixing Client Credentials code with code for Authentication. You should only use the full code [with user authentication](https://github.com/spotipy-dev/spotipy#with-user-authentication).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works, I tested it with my setup information.
I think you missing your credentials or not set up correctly in your the developer dashboard.

But as mentioned 'Ximzend' mixed Client Credential Flow and Authorization Code Flow.

Authorization Code Flow
[Authorization Code Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/code-flow) vs. [Client Credentials Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/client-credentials-flow)

and it would be better my version code.
It is not a necessary username. I need to log in the user.

as get-songs-v1.py

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
import spotipy.util as util

MY_ID   = "<your client id>"
SECRET = "<your client secret>"

# Authorise
spoti = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=MY_ID,
                                                           client_secret=SECRET))
spoti.trace = False

username = "<your user name>"
scope    = "user-read-currently-playing"
redirect_uri = "<your redirect URI>"
token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope, client_id=MY_ID, client_secret=SECRET, redirect_uri=redirect_uri)

# sp as spotify - makes it easier
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)

current_track = sp.current_user_playing_track()
song = current_track["item"]
song_artist = current_track["item"]["artists"][0]["name"]
print(song_artist," - ", song['name'])
```

Result v1.py

[image]

I copy my credential information from the dashboard.

[image]

username copy from my user account of profile
[image]

Simple version v2

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth

sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(
    client_id = '<your client id>',
    client_secret= '<your client secret>',
    redirect_uri='<your redirect URI>',
    scope='user-read-currently-playing'))

def Get_Current_Song():
    response_current_track = sp.current_user_playing_track()
    if response_current_track  is not None and response_current_track["item"] is not None:
        song = response_current_track["item"]
        print(song['artists'][0]['name'], " - ", song['name'])

Get_Current_Song()
```

Result of v2

[image]

#2 Get songs name and artist name.

get artist name <- ['item']['artists'][0]['name']

get song name <- ['item']['album']['artist'][0]['name']

VS code with debugging of Python.
[image]

OR Postman
how to get token in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75877454/spotipy-authorization-code-flow-only-valid-bearer-authentication-error/75883346#75883346)

`[` means array, you need to access by index zero.

[image]