# Status 401 message Spotify's API

Tags: python, token, spotify, http-status-code-401

I'm doing a project using the Spotify's API, and after watching and following some examples, I've got a message:

> Status 401 message unauthorized.

This is when I try to use any function from the documentation, and I've read about the token and saw some solutions but most of them are in JSON, and I don't know JSON, I'm still learning.

```py
# Function to get the token
def token():
    """ 
    Function to get the token for the Spotify API, without this the API won't work.
    You don't have to change anything in this function.
    """
    auth_string = f"{SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID}:{SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET}"
    auth_bytes = auth_string.encode("utf-8")
    auth_encoded = base64.b64encode(auth_bytes)

    url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Basic {auth_encoded.decode('utf-8')}",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
    data = {"grant_type": "client_credentials"}
    result = post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
    json_result = json.loads(result.content)
    token = json_result["access_token"]
    return token

# Function to get the authorization header
def get_auth_header(token):
    """
    Function to get the authorization header for the Spotify API.
    You don't have to change anything in this function.
    """
    return {"Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"}

def my_profile():
    """
    Function to get the profile of the user.
    """
    token_ = token()
    headers = get_auth_header(token_)
    url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me"
    result = get(url, headers=headers)
    return json.loads(result.content)


me = my_profile()
print(me)
```

Comment: try `print(token_)` and make sure that it's what you expect (i.e. the right token)

Comment: that's the issue, this is the token_ printed = BQAtXe8lqnqAnkDCu4VqtW78HoK3uH1fSl1n6KkScfjj_D5eSzY8_b1zE0_k2WVp_W_Uwv63yZq0Hg7maaLS1gDUcE3BTjtH_K29IP5qbi07p6pJs-E. And that's what I expected but still not working

Comment: Client Credential can't get the user profile.
See this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76188057/current-playlist-with-spotipy/76191758#76191758)