# Get access token using oauth authorization code flow without setting a web server

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, authorization

I need to develope a console application that calls an API that is protected with oauth2 protocol.
I don't want to develop a web server to  capture the authorization code callback since this is an on premise application behind a firewall.

Is there any way to use middleware server to act as callback so it will handle the callback ,get the authorization code and exchange it for access token ? I will connect to this server by api to get the access token.

I don't want to handle with setup eeb server and expose it publicly. I'm looking for a solution where I can register my application in sort of third party proxy server that can handle the authorization for me.

Any ideas ?

I tried some proxy oauth providers but I couldn't find any of them providing this kind of service

Answer (score 0):

Usably you have to implement web server at client side with setting a web server for [Authorization Code Grant](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.1).

This diagram copy from [`The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.1) standard documentation.

```
 +----------+
 | Resource |
 |   Owner  |
 |          |
 +----------+
      ^
      |
     (B)
 +----|-----+          Client Identifier      +---------------+
 |         -+----(A)-- & Redirection URI ---->|               |
 |  User-   |                                 | Authorization |
 |  Agent  -+----(B)-- User authenticates --->|     Server    |
 |          |                                 |               |
 |         -+----(C)-- Authorization Code ---<|               |
 +-|----|---+                                 +---------------+
   |    |                                         ^      v
  (A)  (C)                                        |      |
   |    |                                         |      |
   ^    v                                         |      |
 +---------+                                      |      |
 |         |>---(D)-- Authorization Code ---------'      |
 |  Client |          & Redirection URI                  |
 |         |                                             |
 |         |<---(E)----- Access Token -------------------'
 +---------+       (w/ Optional Refresh Token)
```

(C)-- Authorization Code - the authorization
server redirects the user-agent back to the client using the
redirection URI provided earlier (in the request or during
client registration).  The redirection URI includes an
authorization code and any local state provided by the client
earlier.

It means `the authorization server redirects the user-agent back to the client` the User Agent have to web server.

The `User Agent` should be web server but It can handle by 3rd party software.

This is example [`spotipy`](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.11.1/#authorization-code-flow). it provide a web server for you.

The token exchange involves sending your secret key, perform this on a secure location, like a backend service, and not from a client such as a browser or from a mobile app.

[This is example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75877454/spotipy-authorization-code-flow-only-valid-bearer-authentication-error/75883346#75883346) of using spotipy web server without implement client web server. The `spotipy` handle (A),(B),(C), (D) and (E) for you. You just config all information( Client ID/Secret and redirect URI) and login once.
The spotipy save access token and using it when you call REST APIs.

If you don't want to web server, you can use [`Client Credentials Grant`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.4)
The client can request an access token using only its client
credentials without web server at client.

```
 +---------+                                  +---------------+
 |         |                                  |               |
 |         |>--(A)- Client Authentication --->| Authorization |
 | Client  |                                  |     Server    |
 |         |<--(B)---- Access Token ---------<|               |
 |         |                                  |               |
 +---------+                                  +---------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways in which a console app can act as an OAuth client. In both cases there is no web server.

**ON BEHALF OF A USER**

In this case the console app runs an authorization code flow and the user authenticates via the system browser. The console app receives the authorization code on a loopback URL such as `http://localhost:5000`. The app then swaps the code for tokens, then sends an access token to APIs. It is the same flow as for a desktop app - for more info see [this post of mine](https://authguidance.com/desktop-apps-overview/).

**ON BEHALF OF ITSELF**

Alternatively a console app can be deployed as a daemon service that runs silently. When there is no user involved, the client credentials flow can be used, as Bench Vue explains above. One example use case might be an end of day batch process.